# Have we met before?

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

If there are $6$ people at a party, then either at least $3$ people met each other before the party or at least $3$ people were strangers before the party.

Solution from Xinfeng Zhou's A practical Guide to Quantitative Finance:

Let's say that you are the $6^{th}$ person at the party. Then by generalized Pigeon Hole Principle, among the remaining $5$ people, we conclude that either at least $3$ people met you or at least $3$ people did not meet you. Now let's explore these two mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive scenarios:

Case 1: Suppose that at least $3$ people have met you before. If two people in this group met each other, you and the pair ($3$ people) met each other. If no pair among these people met each other, then these people ($\ge 3$ people) did not meet each other. In either sub-case, the conclusion holds.

Case 2: Suppose at least $3$ people have not met you before. If two people in this group did not meet each other, you and the pair ($3$ people) did not meet each other. If all pairs among these people knew each other, then these people ($\ge 3$ people) met each other. Again, in either sub-case, the conclusion holds.

My doubt is this:
How can we say that either three people met me, or three did not? I can visualize the pigeon(person from $1$ to $5$) and hole (either met or did not meet), but if we look at the five people present here, each could have independently met or did not meet me.

Comment: The pigeonhole principle does not depend on the independence, and is in fact stronger than that (you could have dependence as well). It says here that, if there are 5 pigeons and 2 holes (as you described), at least 1 hole has >= 5/2 = 3 people in it.

Comment: Rather than remembering the $+1$ or $-1$ terms in some formulations of the pigeonhole principle, I prefer to go through its (very easy) derivation from scratch: If you knew only 2 of the others and you didn't know only 2 of them,  then that makes only 4 others altogether, whereas in fact there are 5 others because you're the 6th.

Comment: The answer to your question is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_on_friends_and_strangers

Answer (score 1):

Mostly to get this out of the unanswered question line:

If you have n lines, at least half are one color. That shows, that at least 3 of 5 lines drawn from any one person, have to be one of the two colors. It then follows, that you can't connect the three with that color line; or you'd make a triangle with those 3. If you connect them all with the opposite color you form the triangle of the opposite color. The relations described by the lines, are symmetric.